# Почему не работает скрипты на разных страницах?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет. Есть многостраничный сайт и файл js который подключается на всех страницах в футере. И вот тут я столкнулся с проблемой. Как вы знайте если js находит ошибку он дальше не выполняет весь код. Так вот у меня около 10 скриптов. И вот 2 скрипт берет значения из Dom дерево первой страницы, а тут он находит данный элемент и пишет мол его нету. И конечно след. 8 скриптов не работают, ибо останавливается на 2. Подскажите пожалуйста как подход тут реализовать. Выносить для каждой страницы отдельные скрипты& . Думаю есть более нормальный способ это сделать. Ведь многостраничные сайты не грузят по 10 файлов JS.

Comment: Речь идет не о 10 скриптах, а о 10 функциях?

Answer (score 2):

Так исправьте скрипт, который кидает ошибку.

Например:

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
```

Замените на :

```
if (document.getElementById('menu')) {
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
}
```

И тогда скрипт будет работать на всех страницах без ошибок.

Comment: Так делать проверку для каждого элемента ?

Comment: Если  у вас древовидная структура этих элементов (один в другом) то достаточно проверять самый верхний, логично же: если нету верхнего то и внутренних не будет.

Comment: Сергей если честно не до конца понял о чем вы. У меня есть скрипт в котором я разделил участки кода на фрагменты с помощью ком. 
К примеру 
// Вывод Pop 1
  code 
// End вывод pop 1

// Одинаковая ширина элементов
  code
// End одинаковая ширина элементов

// Получаем массив из чекбоксов активныХ
  code
// ENd

И таких к примеру 10. Я перехожу на вторую страницу, и пишу 11 фрагмент, который нужен для конкретно второй страницы. Но 2 фрагмент дал сбой ибо он не нашел блока , и выдал ошибку. И за чего весь остальный не читается. И как предлагайте сделать?